# open route .show when onchange a dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

In my view tests.index is it possible to open my route tests.show by clicking in a select dropdown where datas comes from database ?

My controller :

```
public function index(Request $request)
{ 
  $tests = DB::table('test')->distinct()->get();
  return view('tests.index')->with('tests', $tests);
}

public function show($id)
{ 
  $test = Test::findOrFail($id); 
  return view('tests.show', compact('test')); 
}
```

My view index :

```
 <select id="apports" type="dropdown-toggle" class="form-control" name="apports" onchange="{{ route("tests.show", $test->id) }}">
<option value="choisir" selected disabled>Choisir</option>
@foreach($tests as $test)
<option class="apports" value="{{$test->id}}">{{$test->apports}}</option>
@endforeach
```

When I put my route here : `onchange` I get the error "Undefined variable: test"
when I add a button below the select like that :

```
<a class="btn btn-small btn-success" href="{{ route("tests.show", $test->id) }}">Show</a>
```

I get always the last id of the table...

I would prefer not have a button, just when I change value in the select, return tests.show... Is someone could help me please ?

Comment: the `$test` variable is only can be called inside `@foreach` loop

Comment: on the top of view `{{dd($test)}}` write this and share display results with me

Comment: yes but i can't put the onchange in the <option> ?

Comment: @BilalAhmed the result is : Undefined variable: test (View: C:\wamp64\www\jmmb4\resources\views\tests\index.blade.php)

Comment: `public function show($id)
{ 
  $test = Test::findOrFail($id); 
  print_r($test);
}`

Comment: replace above code in function show

Comment: Bilal Ahmed did you read the Controller code? In the index view, the $test variable doesn't exist. It only has access to the $tests collection.

Comment: @gbalduzzi in Controller they have two function `index` and `show`..

Comment: Yes but index view in only called by the index function, the show function is not called when going to the index page

Comment: ok i have it : i had to change my value="{{$test->id}}" by my route value=="{{ route("tests.show", $test->id) }}". And put in the select onchange="top.location.href = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is a javascript snippet to read the select option change and redirect you.

```
<select id="apports" type="dropdown-toggle" class="form-control" name="apports">
    <option value="choisir" selected disabled>Choisir</option>
    @foreach($tests as $test)
        <option class="apports" value="{{ route("tests.show", $test->id) }}">{{ $test->apports }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>

<script>
    $('select').on('change', function (e) {
        var link = $("option:selected", this).val();
        if (link) {
            location.href = link;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$test` variable is not set in the index view, only the `$tests` collection is available because you load the view with that:

```
return view('tests.index')->with('tests', $tests);
```

You need to use some JavaScript to achieve what you are looking for.
In the index template:

```
<select id="apports" type="dropdown-toggle" class="form-control" name="apports" onchange="goToTestPage(this.value)">
```

Then in your JavaScript file:

```
function goToTestPage(id) {
  window.location.href = "link to your show route/"+id;
}
```

If the test id is changed dynamically by the user, you can't set it on PHP because PHP is executed before the user actually does the selection, so you have to rely on JavaScript